# Deploying just the web application front end (jsp) in Amazon Web Service confusion

Tags: amazon-web-services

Hi I have built a web application for mobile users. Now I have a project to deploy it in the amazon cloud. The web application will just consists of the jsp pages, in lay man term just the website without any database because the database will be placed locally.

The web application which is supposed to be in the cloud, will send a request in JSON format to a web service client that will be hosted in a public LAN IP.

The wev service client will then call a web method (web service locally that is connected to eqms to retrieve data). And the cycle reversed sending it back to the web service client, then back to the web application in the cloud and to the mobile user.

The main question is i am confuse which one to use or is it the right AWS to use considering my requirements.

My choice would be Amazon Cloudfront. Any experts out there can give me a guide on this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cloudfront is a static content distribution network service for caching your static assets at  edge locations around the world.  It doesn't run code.  S3 is for storing static files, which can be accessed directly (cheaper) or can serve as the backing store for Cloudfront (faster) and S3 also doesn't run code.

I think you'll find that that you're looking for is EC2 (Elastic Compute Cloud).  The "jsp" pages are not static pages, they're code that generates active content, right?  They'd need to be executed by the web server?  That web server reads the client requests, crafts the JSON message to request data, gets the data back, does something with the data, and returns it to the client?  Sounds like EC2 to me... or, depending on what your application's actual requirements are, there is a set of services that includes EC2 with some other AWS services providing supporting roles.  This is marketed as [Elastic Beanstalk](http://aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/).

Comment: Hi Michael, yup you are right as in the flow of my project. 

I have 3 web servers all using Tomcat.

I just came across the AmazonBeanStalk Service which deploys the web application to the cloud (via Netbeans IDE). 

It has only a few steps which seems great anyway to deploy to cloud using netbeans ide.

Thanks Michael, at least u have enlightened me about it.